# What is the best board to install behind a glue up tub surround?

Tags: shower, bathtub, adhesive, cement-board, backer-board

I would think it would make sense to install a waterproof board like GoBoard or DensShield behind a fiberglass tub surround, but I can’t find an adhesive that specifically states that it is compatible with these products. I’m hesitant to use greenboard when for not much more money I can have a waterproof wall. Cement board is a pain to work with and liquid nails gets mixed reviews adhering to it.

Comment: Do you expect the surround to leak? Standard drywall has always been fine for me.

Comment: Seems like cheap insurance to use something better than drywall?

Comment: FG tub surround is 100% waterproof already.  whatever is behind it will not make it any more waterproof that it already is.

Comment: Insurance against what? If you have a leak and your backer doesn't disintegrate, the lumber behind and below it will rot, or whatever is below that. Unless you're building a tub for your shower, do a good job of installing your surround and don't worry about it.

Comment: That’s why I don’t want to use a traditional cement tile backer. If your surround leaks at a seam onto a 100% waterproof backer it can’t get to your framing.

Comment: What will you put behind the waterproof backer board in case it leaks? And what will you put behind that?

Answer (score 1):

Most use standard drywall. If you feel better using dens shield or another WP drywall that would be fine tub surround adhesive must be used to avoid discoloring bleed through on the surround. Two adhesive makers indicate they will work well. Honestly if they will bond to ceramic tile they will bond to most anything.

From the [manufacturer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000TJQQUK):

> Liquid Nails LN715-10oz Tub Surround and Shower Wall Adhesive is a durable construction adhesive that provides an exceptional waterproof bond under extreme conditions. LN715 Tub Surround and Shower Wall is recommended for bonding most plastic and fiberglass tub and shower surrounds to drywall, plywood, greenboard, cement backerboard, and ceramic tiles

And another [manufacturer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-Power-Grab-10-fl-oz-Tub-Surround-Adhesive-1363138/202020457)

> Loctite PowerGrab 10 fl. oz. Tub Surround Adhesive with low odor, low VOC and easy water cleanup is an ideal interior construction adhesive. It is designed to bond most plastic surround tubs to waterproof drywall, wood, sanded tile board and ceramic tile.

Comment: This makes no mention of waterproof tile backer. Cement board is not waterproof. You would think ceramic tile would be slicker and less pourous than GoBoard?

Comment: Liquid Nails Fuze-It looks promising. Doesn't say anything about bleed through. Liquid Nails' Fuze-It All Surface is a construction adhesive that bonds everything to everything (except polyethylene and polypropylene) and it even bonds in any weather condition. Hot, cold, wet or dry, Fuze-It All Surface offers a durable, flexible bond that is two times stronger than fasteners alone.

Comment: @user1594257  all purpose product vs specifically made for one purpose.  I would not use fuzeit on a tub surround unless I was assured by manufacturer that it was recommended for that specific application.

Comment: Locative Power Grab Tun Surround specifically states > Does not work on: •cement board, Durarock, or waterproof tile backer. •overlaps on multi-piece units •two non-pour outs surfaces